# How to handle a function to work both with and without arguments

Tags: python, string

I wrote a function counting occurence of letters in a given string. It is working when called with a string argument, but I would also like to handle it without arguemnt (to return an empty dictionary).

```
from string import ascii_letters

def letter_frequency(word):
    result = dict()

    for letter in ascii_letters:
        if word.count(letter) != 0:
           result[letter] = word.count(letter)
        return result
```

I tried to use *args instead of a word as an argument, but then it works like there is always an empty argument.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, notice that the last line should be outside the loop:

```
def letter_frequency(word=""):
    result = dict()    
    for letter in ascii_letters:
        if word.count(letter) != 0:
           result[letter] = word.count(letter)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Set an argument to a default value to make it optional. If the user inputs a value for the argument, it will override the default value.

```
def display(required_arg, optional_arg1 = "1"):
    print(required_arg, optional_arg1)

display("a")
# OUTPUT
# a 1

display("a", "b")
# OUTPUT
# a b
```

Answer (score 0):

hello it is possible you can use

```
 word=None
```

but know there's a twist the user has to call the function like

```
letter_frequency(word="Sample")
#and for without argument simply
letter_frequency()
```

and know you have to also check if word is None

```
if word==None:
    #do something
```